# Gravity forms repeater with upload file error

Tags: repeater, gravity

I'm building a form with a repeater and a file upload inside. When I submit the form, the input file filed always give me the error: **There was an error while uploading the file. Error code: 1
Add**

Here's my code:

```
  $uploadfiles = GF_Fields::create( array(
    'type'   => 'fileupload',
    'id'     => 1006, // The Field ID must be unique on the form
    'formId' => $form['id'],
    'multipleFiles' => false,
    'allowedExtensions' => 'gif,jpg,jpeg,png,txt,rtf,pdf,doc,docx,odt,ppt,pptx,odp,xls,xlsx,ods,xml',
    'description' => '<br>Relevant documents: our transport way bill, probill, photos, etc.<br>Files must be less than 2 MB.<br>Allowed extensions: gif jpg jpeg png txt rtf pdf doc docx odt ppt pptx odp xls xlsx ods xml.',
    'label'  => __('Please attach any relevant document', 'srx'),
    'pageNumber'  => 1, // Ensure this is correct
  ));

  // Create a repeater for the team members and add the name and email fields as the fields to display inside the repeater.
  $team = GF_Fields::create( array(
      'type'             => 'repeater',
      'description'      => '',
      'id'               => 1000, // The Field ID must be unique on the form
      'formId'           => $form['id'],
      'label'            => __('Products', 'srx'),
      'addButtonText'    => __('Add product', 'srx'),
      'removeButtonText' => __('Remove product', 'srx'),
      'maxItems'         => 100, // Optional
      'pageNumber'       => 1, // Ensure this is correct
      'fields'           => array( $reference, $quantity, $product, $lista, $uploadfiles ), // Add the fields here.
  ) );
```

Even tho the field is not required, it gives me the error anyways.
Another question I have is about the use of multipleFiles = true. This doesn't work at all. Any idea why ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

The Repeater API does not currently support File Upload fields. Here's a full list of known limitations:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/repeater-fields/#limitations

If you need repeating file uploads, check out Gravity Forms Nested Forms:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/